# What's the easiest way to selectively copy applications and their settings to another machine?

Tags: macos, migration, migration-assistant

I'm looking for something like Migration Assistant, but which will let me choose which apps I want to copy/transfer.

I want to transfer some apps and their settings/preferences from one machine to another.

Something like an App Cleaner but which will copy instead of Trash the support files?